# What has caused this f-curve to be inactive?

Tags: animation, fcurves

The f-curve for the Y location is still there, but it isn't working. I must have clicked or pressed something without realizing, but I can't find what. It shows up in white with all its keyframes intact, and the object isn't moving when I scrub.

[image: screenshot of f-curve editor with channel in white]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have accidentally pressed the 'speaker' icon next to the f-curve in the *Graph Editor*, which is used to temporarily disable (mute) f-curves:

[image]

Click it to enable the f-curve again:

Comment: Ah yes, there it is. My old eyes didn't notice that little difference. :)